# mysqldump gerando o mesmo arquivo com tamanho diferente

Tags: mysql, linux, dump, mysqldump

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou tendo um problema bizarro ao usar o `mysqldump`, vou tentar explicar da melhor forma possível.

Tenho 4 databases, e diariamente é feito um dump de cada base, gerando arquivos diferentes, porém um desses arquivos gerados varia muito de tamanho, por exemplo ontem o arquivo `.sql` da base principal ficou com o tamanho de 3.2G, e hoje, o `.sql` da mesma base foi gerado com um tamanho de 2G, e não entendo o que pode estar acontecendo.

Esse é o comando usado:

`mysqldump --user=root --password=senha --databases databasetal --single-transaction > database.sql 2> database.log`

(Alterei alguns nomes e a senha por questões de segurança)

Esse comando roda todo dia às 2:00h, e nunca há erros no log gerado, apenas isso:

> mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Quem puder dar uma luz, eu ficaria muito grato...

Answer (score 1):

Bruno, você armazena no banco algum tipo de log? Pode ser que exista alguma tabela que esteja variando de tamanho, você pode fazer o seguinte teste, ao invés de armazenar em um arquivo apenas, pode separar em vários arquivos que são relativos a cada tabela e então analisar qual tabela está essa diferença.

Eu sempre utilizo o mysql workbench para exportar em vários arquivos, não tentei fazer por outro modo.

Comment: Imaginei que pode haver alguma rotina que manipula alguma(s) tabela(s), mas vou validar isso mesmo achando meio improvável.